# Undefined references linking sqlite3pp

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to compile sqlite3pp. Source is from http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp

1) `g++ ../src/*.cpp -c`
-> produces 3 .o file sqlite3pp.o, sqlite3ppext.o and testaggregate.o

2) `ar crf libsqlite3pp.a *.o`
-> generate new file called libsqlite3pp.a

3) `g++ -shared *.o -o sqlite3pp.dll`
-> multiple undefined reference to sqlite3_*

4) `g++ -shared *.o -lsqlite3pp -o sqlite3pp.dll`
-> same errors as previous

5) `g++ -shared *.o -lsqlite3 -o sqlite.dll`
-> undefined reference to sqlite3_open_v2

Why does this last error occur?

Comment: Line 3 seems wrong. Is it a typo ?

Comment: Uups there is a typo.
g++ -shared *.o -o sqlite3pp.dll -> multiple undefined reference to sqlite3_

Comment: What version of SQLite are you linking against? `sqlite3_open_v2()` first showed up in 3.5

Comment: Stupid mistake for me. I have accidentally downloaded very old version of sqlite3. Now 3.8.2 and everything were linked properly.